# Can I clean the fabric from my stroller in a washer and dryer?

Tags: cleaning, stroller

The seat cover on my Maclaran (Quest) stroller is pretty filthy, and it all unsnaps, but the Maclaran site doesn't seem to have any info on whether you can machine wash it (or how to wash it at all).

Anyone have any guidance?  If the washer is safe, does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't there be a tag somewhere on the cover specifying what kind of fabric it's made out of?  Assuming there is a tag (and it doesn't already include washing instructions), you can use other clothes you have (made out of the same fabric) for washing instructions.

I found [this link](http://us.maclarenbaby.com/buggies/87/blog/master-db/category/4/page-1) on the Maclaran website that suggests this is the case (and provides a fallback if you can't find it):

> How do I wash the buggy seat fabric?
>
> Look for the fabric care instructions label on your seat. Most seats are designed to be hand washed in cold water, or sponge cleaned.

In my experience with the strollers we've gone through, if it feels like it has some sort of foam padding to help keep its shape, it'll be easier to get cleaner just by wiping it down - I find the washing machine doesn't work as well unless the fabric can "bunch up" (to rub against itself or other items in the wash).

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are cardboard inserts, I would toss it in the washing machine and start it on a cold hand-wash program.

If it's just a little dirty, a soapy sponge and brush with lukewarm water should be enough.

Don't tumble-dry it because the heat could damage the inner materials.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a 2nd hand pram, it was past filthy. Seriously gross, probably shouldn't have purchased but... anyhow... I washed the removable fabric in the washing machine. I assumed there was a piece if firm foam in the back and it was infact cardboard. So be careful! Seriously why cardboard? The little people that go in these things spill food, drink and... worse! I'm mad now, at the pram and myself!